# How to get the result datetime from “CronExpression.GetNextValidTimeAfter(DateTimeOffset)” quartz scheduler method in UTC±00:00 format?

Tags: c#, datetime, quartz.net

I am passing an UTC±00:00 time to the GetNextValidTimeAfter() method in Quartz scheduler to calculate the next valid time for scheduling based on a specific cron expression but since my system time is in PST, the result is returned in UTC−08:00 format but I need to get the result in UTC±00:00 format.

```
CronExpression expression = new CronExpression("0 0 1 1/1 * ? *"); //Daily 1 AM
DateTime EasternTimeUTC = new DateTime(2020, 3, 7, 6, 00, 0); //Corresponding UTC time for EST time 7th March 1 AM
DateTimeOffset? nextFireUTCTime = expression.GetNextValidTimeAfter(EasternTimeUTC);
```

nextFireUTCTime returns the next valid datetime as 3/8/2020 9:00 AM which is in UTC−08:00 format since my system time zone is in PST but i need the result in UTC±00:00 which should be 3/8/2020 6:00 AM. How do I get to this value?

Since I couldn't find a proper solution to the above issue, I tried the below.

My system will always be in PST timezone which means the result that I get from GetNextValidTimeAfter() quartz scheduler method will always return in UTC−08:00 format. To get the output in EST timezone format, I am subtracting either 8 or 7 hours from the result based on DST but this solution fails when the scheduled time falls between 8th March 12.00 AM - 1.59 AM.

```
CronExpression expression = new CronExpression("0 0 1 1/1 * ? *"); 
DateTime EasternTimeUTC = new DateTime(2020, 3, 7, 6, 00, 0); 
DateTimeOffset? nextFireUTCTime = expression.GetNextValidTimeAfter(EasternTimeUTC); 
TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime UTCNextTime1 = DateTime.UtcNow;
if (timeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(nextFireUTCTime.GetValueOrDefault()))
   {
            UTCNextTime1 = nextFireUTCTime.Value.DateTime.AddHours(-7);
   }
else
   {
            UTCNextTime1 = nextFireUTCTime.Value.DateTime.AddHours(-8);
   }
```

Comment: can you use DateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.utcdatetime?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: You can use UTC.  There is no difference in the datetime object between local time and UTC.  The DataTime object just gets displayed differently based on the Culture settings of the PC.  If you changed the timezone on your PC the UTC time still displays the same.

Comment: @DmitriTsoy I tried your suggestion but it returns me the same result which is 3/8/2020 9:00 AM

Comment: @jdweng When I change my system time zone to EST, the datetime value returned via GetNextValidTimeAfter() is also changed based on that timezone corresponding UTC which is UTC-05:00

Comment: That is what I said.  In PST you are getting -08:00 and in EST you are getting -05:00 which means the UTC time is not changing.  So if you take the current DataTime object and add X you will get the next scheduled time.  It doesn't matter if you add X to UTC or local time the results will be the same.

Comment: @jdweng Can you read my latest comment to the 1 answer posted to this question below and let me know your suggestions?

Comment: You change makes no sense.  Why would the next event sometimes be 7 hours and other times be 8 hours?  UTC does not change when going from Standard Time to Daylight Time.  What does you scheduled Time List look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the DateTime you're passing in is UTC and set the TimeZone of the CronExpression

```
CronExpression expression = new CronExpression("0 0 1 1/1 * ? *"); //Daily 1 AM
expression.TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime EasternTimeUTC = new DateTime(2020, 3, 7, 6, 00, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc); //Corresponding UTC time for EST time 7th March 1 AM
DateTimeOffset? nextFireUTCTime = expression.GetNextValidTimeAfter(EasternTimeUTC);
```

Comment: DateTime(2020, 3, 7, 6, 00, 0) - This is my UTC time and I need next valid time based on this UTC time.

Comment: If you add the DateTimeKind in the suggestion above, the CronExpression should return your date in UTC - is that not working for you?

Comment: If i try your method, i get the next valid time as 3/7/2020 9:00 AM but the result I need is 3/8/2020 6:00 AM

Comment: 3/7/2020 9:00 AM PST == 3/7/2020 1:00 AM UTC
But you're comparing that to EST? Should your query time not be the PST equivalent?

I've updated my response to the PST version, which it seems is your time zone

Comment: The functionality I am trying to accomplish is, an user can choose any time zone from picklist and then specify a start time and also specify a cron expression. Now, I need to convert the specified timezone time to UTC and then pass it to GetNextValidTimeAfter() method to get the next scheduled time in same UTC format but the result is returned in my system timezone UTC format every time(i.e. UTC-8 if my system timezone is in PST or UTC-5 if my system timezone is in  EST).

Comment: I see - then you also need to set the TimeZone of the CronExpression - answer updated